# Does anyone know of a mouse gtf that includes cds, tss, and promoters?

Tags: mouse, bioinformatics, genome

I am looking for a mouse gtf to run with cufflinks that includes data on promoters, cds,  and tss. So far, I have only been able to locate a gtf with data on genes and isoforms.

Thanks.

Comment: ask biostars: http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: http://www.biostars.org/p/63135

Answer (score 0):

there is no a standard region for promoter. For tss you can just take the start position of the gene, and for promoter you can take, +-1000 nt around the tss, but it is up to you. There is some kind of standard to take 2000 nt around the tss.

Although if you want to run cufflink with that file, I don't see the point in tss. Maybe just in promoters. Or do a small region around de tss, but it would be inside the promoter region.

I think that you can easily do this with awk.

hope it give some help.
Maybe if you explain what do you want to do, other people know other options for your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the Ensemble website has a gtf as such. you can also go to igenome: http://support.illumina.com/sequencing/sequencing_software/igenome.html 
and select the version you want. let me know if this doesn't work. I can always send you my gtf file that i am using for mm10